# How to write this Curl code to Magento 2 code?

Tags: magento2, curl, curl-request

I am calling third party API using below methods:

```
public function setCredentials($data)
{

    $curl = curl_init('https://example_url.com/');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($curl); 
    curl_close($curl);
}
```

i have tried some of the examples here but I still get errors. How to curl in magento 2?

Comment: what error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

Here I have write curl code

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl
 */
protected $_curl;

/**
 * @param Context                             $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl
) {
    $this->_curl = $curl;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function setCredentials($params)
{
    //if the method is get
    $this->_curl->get($url);
    //if the method is post
    $this->_curl->post($url, $params);
    //response will contain the output in form of JSON string
    $response = $this->_curl->getBody();
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be returning a response?